# Не работает программа для объединения нескольких файлов в один

Tags: python, python-3.x

написал простецкую программу для объединения текстовых файлов на python(с имеющимся внутри данными) в один. Программа работает с большим нюансом, сами данные, которые лежат в тех файлах, которые я хочу объединить пропадают в конечном объединённом файле. Что необходимо изменить или добавить?

```
inputText = []
ark = input('Введите файлы для объединения : ')
while True:
    ark = input('Введите файлы для объединения : ')
    if ark == '': break
name = input('Введите название нового файла : ')
for file in ark:
    with open(file,'r') as file:
        inputText.extend(file.readlines())
with open(name,'w') as output:
    for line in inputText:
        output.write(line)
```

Comment: У вас в `ark` в итоге же пусто будет. Вы никуда не собираете то, что туда вводят, а выход из цикла происходит когда в `ark` пусто.

Comment: У вас какая-то каша из переменных. Давайте разбираться. Почему у вас строковая переменная `ark` используюется для итерации по названиям файлов?

Comment: И еще, не советую переиспользовать итерационную переменную для открываемого дескриптора файла. Не нужно мешать между собой `file` из цикла и `file` из конструкции `with open` в этом же цикле. Переименуйте что-то из этого

Comment: Здравствуйте, данную конструкцию из ark думал сделать как цикл для ввода нескольких файлов в процесс. Цикл создан, чтобы закончить этот, когда строка пустая при вводе он завершается, т.е. завершается указание файлов, которые нужно объединить, сначала пытался вместо ark в цикле: while True: использовать переменную s, но попытки не увенчались успехом. Сделал вот такой код, это вы имели в виду переименовать или что-то другое? inputText = []
ark = input('Введите файлы для объединения : ')
while True:
    s = input('Введите файлы для объединения : ')
    if s == '': break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можете попробовать такой код:

```py
inputText = []
ark = []
ark.append(input('Введите файлы для объединения : '))

while True:
    inp = input('Введите файлы для объединения : ')
    if inp == '': 
        break
    else:
        ark.append(inp)

name = input('Введите название нового файла : ')

for fl in ark:
    with open(fl, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        inputText.extend(file.readlines())

with open(name, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    output.writelines(inputText)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но не работает, пишет: line 19, in <module>
    output.writelines(line)
NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: Поправил. Там должен быть список строк `inputText`

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо большое за помощь, всё заработало благодаря вам)

Comment: ну, раз заработало, то отметьте ответ как решение

Comment: Извините, чуть не забыл, всё сделано